# My title product is out of the template woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to customize my single product page in woocommerce. But when I try to custom the title with hooks it does not work because the title of my product is "out of the template".
When I check the source page I have this :

```html
My product title
<div id="woocommerce"> 
 <div class="single-product" data-product-page-preselected-id="0">
  <div class="woocommerce-notices-wrapper"></div>
  <div id="product-185" class="product type-product post-185 status-publish first instock product_cat-textile has-post-thumbnail shipping-taxable product-type-simple">
...
</div>
```

I thought the title should be in the DIV "product-id" and in a H1 (https://www.hsrtech.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-cheatsheet-single-product-page/) but not.

This is my index.php :

```php
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; else : ?>
    <p>Nothing</p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

How can I fix this ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Woocommerce have own templates and hooks and filters.

Comment: Yes as I said, I use hooks but my problem is : I don't know what is this title because when I remove product title, it still there.... So I don't know what is it and what filter or hooks I had to use.